# JSONObject(String) missing?

Tags: java, string, url, json

Searching up on google I found this solution to read json strings from URL:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new URL("https://somelink.com"), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

The problem is that there is no JSONObject(String) constructor, why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thin you use `google-gson`, use [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/), there is constructor:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
String myData = obj.getString("myData");
```

Comment: do you use `org.json` ?